# How to access downloads folder in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to download files to `Downloads` folder and read. it is a root folder like photos and videos.

But `Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder` isn't available for phone and I don't see it in `KnownFolders` like `Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;`

Also I tried `C:\Data\Users\Public\Downloads\` it gives an unauthorized result.

I see some apps has access to it, but how?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a file or folder picker.
I'm not sure if you want the user to chose a file, or if you want to pick a file yourself, but i think the best way to achieve this is using something like:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

or

```
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
folderPicker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```

Comment: @user3293835 That's not possible for security reasons.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT But there are apps have access to it on the Store. (file managers for example)

Comment: @user3293835 Bring forth proof.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pocket-file-manager/56dd9c3d-fe0a-4ceb-84b0-043e58e55b19

Comment: It doesn't have access to the Downloads folder.

Comment: Note that folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation is ignored on Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: @ClausJørgensen here is one app that can read Documents, Downloads, and Ringtones in internal storages. I too want to make an app like this but still cannot understand how the developer of this app achieve it. 
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/folders-pro-advanced-file-manager/69eaa9d6-060e-4e82-ba40-12df2fe2e285

Answer (score 2):

To complete the previous answer, it is possible to access such a folder, but only after a first access to it through FolderPicker.

The trick is to use the StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList. It is what file explorers applications do. It will give you a token that you can save in your IsolatedStorage, so you can later access the Downloads folder directly, thanks to the token.

See there for a walkthrough with StorageApplicationPermissions.mostRecentlyUsedList : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh972603 but the principles are quite the same with FutureAccessList.

Comment: Excellent @StratocastFlo Finally you saved my day.